# Cannot set font on edit control

Tags: c++, winapi

I'm having difficulty setting a font for an edit control. I've used `SendMessage(hwnd, WM_FONT, args)` but it appears to have no effect. I added `EM_SETMODIFY` message but that also has had no effect. Here's the code I've been using:

```
    class EditBox : public Wide::OS::EditBox {
        HWND box;
        std::unique_ptr<std::decay<decltype(*HFONT())>::type, decltype(&DeleteObject)> font; 
        Math::AbsolutePoint curr_pos;
        Math::AbsolutePoint curr_dim;
    public:
        void SetFont(std::shared_ptr<Render::Font> f) {
            font = decltype(this->font)(CreateFontIndirect(&dynamic_cast<Wide::Direct3D9::Font*>(f.get())->GetLogFont()), &DeleteObject);
            SendMessage(box, WM_SETFONT, reinterpret_cast<WPARAM>(font.get()), true);
            SendMessage(box, EM_SETMODIFY, true, 0);
        }
        EditBox(std::shared_ptr<Render::Font> font, HWND owner, Math::AbsolutePoint position, Math::AbsolutePoint dimensions, HINSTANCE hinst) 
        : curr_pos(position), curr_dim(dimensions), font(CreateFontIndirect(&dynamic_cast<Wide::Direct3D9::Font*>(font.get())->GetLogFont()), &DeleteObject){
            box = CreateWindowEx(
                0, 
                L"EDIT", 
                L"Type here", 
                WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD | WS_TABSTOP | ES_LEFT,
                position.x,
                position.y,
                dimensions.x,
                dimensions.y,
                owner,
                0,
                hinst,
                0);
            /*SetWindowSubclass(box, [](HWND hwnd, UINT msg, WPARAM wparam, LPARAM lparam, UINT_PTR, DWORD_PTR) -> LRESULT {
                if (msg != WM_PAINT)
                    return DefSubclassProc(hwnd, msg, wparam, lparam);
                PAINTSTRUCT paint;
                BeginPaint(hwnd, &paint);

                EndPaint(hwnd, &paint);
                return 0;
            }, 0, 0);*/
            SendMessage(box, WM_SETFONT, reinterpret_cast<WPARAM>(font.get()), true);
            SendMessage(box, EM_SETMODIFY, true, 0);
        }
        ~EditBox() { DestroyWindow(box); }
    };
```

I checked the values on the LOGFONT I'm getting back and they are quite reasonable, but I could show them upon request.

Any suggestions as to why the font is not being altered?

Comment: Did you verify that `CreateFontIndirect()` is returning a non-NULL `HFONT` handle?

Comment: It is odd to see `std::unique_ptr` being used for an `HFONT` in this manner. I assume you are using `std:decay` to dereference the `HFONT` type to a base type that gets converted back to a pointer by `std::unique_ptr`, is that right? I wouldn't use `std::unique_ptr` in this manner, since you could just call `DeleteObject()` directly in the class's `SetFont()` method and destructor.

Comment: Yes, because `*HFONT()` gives `HFONT__&` originally, which `unique_ptr` can't work with. And I could do that but, exception safety and such? it's not a wise move. I will check the return value of CreateFontIndirect. Didn't occur to me that it could fail because I already have this font with an ID3DXFont and am rendering with it.

Comment: It doesn't appear to be NULL.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The damn variable shadowing in the constructor. The pointer being passed is actually a `Render::Font*`, not the `HFONT` from the stored variable. I, of course, did not correctly test whether it was `SetFont` which did not work, or the constructor which did not work. If only Windows used actual functions instead of those icky messages so I didn't have to `reinterpret_cast`, woulda had a nice compiler error.

Comment: +1 for bloody honesty :) And in fairness, this serves as a general example of how to troubleshoot problems effectively